# How to receive messages in group chats using telegram bot api

Tags: telegram-bot

My telegram bot receives messages sent by user to my bot in private chats but not receives messages sent by users in group chats. Any options/api for getting group chat messages also,.

Answer (score 128, accepted):

Talk to [@botfather](http://telegram.me/botfather) and disable the privacy mode.

Comment: take into account that you have to set it off before adding to chat. Otherwise you have to remove it and add it again

Comment: That is not really true, you can do it before, after, during... whenever you want.

Comment: I'm not sure, but kicking the bot and adding it back solved my problem. Took me hours= =. **you have to set it off before adding to chat**

Comment: Another note is that the bot MUST be an admin on that group, regardless of the privacy settings. Otherwise, it will NOT be able to read any of the group messages.

Comment: No, either the bot needs to be an admin OR privacy mode needs to be disabled.

Answer (score 93):

Sequence within a BotFather chat:

**You**: /setprivacy

**BotFather**: Choose a bot to change group messages settings.

**You**: @your_name_bot

**BotFather**: 'Enable' - your bot will only receive messages that either start with the '/' symbol or mention the bot by username.

'Disable' - your bot will receive all messages that people send to groups.

Current status is: ENABLED

**You**: Disable

**BotFather**: Success! The new status is: DISABLED. /help

Comment: I've spent like 2 hours trying to figure this out. Thanks bud!

Comment: I want to make an addition. I have noticed that if you give your bot the administrative rights in the group, than it has ability to see all messages, regardless of /setprivacy setting.

Answer (score 9):

By default A Bot will receive only messages addressed to it by any user directly via posting by `/command@YourBot any message you send`.
After that it vill be available via getUpdates API call.
In browser it will be:

```
https://api.telegram.org/botToken/getupdates
```

Find the related message in output JSON and grab chatId. It will allow you to answer back with:

```
https://api.telegram.org/botToken/sendmessage?chat_id=123456788&text=My Answer
```

Comment: I'm getting {"ok":false,"error_code":401,"description":"Unauthorized"} when I call getupdates

Comment: OK, that's because it requires offset and limit parameters

Comment: try this
https: //api.telegram.org/bot{token}/sendMessage?chat_id=<chat_id>&text=<Enter your text here>

Answer (score 4):

Make your bot by admin in group.

Answer (score 3):

You can access all avaliable settings from all of your bots by sending `/mybots` to `Botfather`. Choose the bot, then **Bot Settings** and **Group Privacy**. If its disable (default), you can tap on **Turn off**.

Now its possible to receive the chat history using `GetUpdates`. This can be done via HTTP API or the frameworks. For example, in C# (.NET Core) like this:

```
var bot = new TelegramBotClient(ApiToken);
var updates = bot.GetUpdatesAsync().Result;
foreach(var update in updates) {
    Console.WriteLine($"{update.ChannelPost.Date} {update.ChannelPost.Text}");
}
```

But keep in mind that this feature has some kind of perfect forward secrecy implemented. So you only get messages that were send *after* group privacy is disabled. As a result, the `GetUpdates` result is empty until some post was made.

Answer (score 3):

if you added your bot before disable the privacy mode, you should remove the bot from the group and add it again