# Telegram Bot "chat not found"

Tags: python, python-requests, telegram, telegram-bot

I have the following code in Python to send a message to myself from a bot.

```
import requests

token = '123456789:ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZABCDEFGHI'
method = 'sendMessage'
myuserid = 1949275XX
response = requests.post(
    url='https://api.telegram.org/bot{0}/{1}'.format(token, method),
    data={'chat_id': myuserid, 'text': 'hello friend'}
).json()
print(response)
```

but this returns `{'description': 'Bad Request: chat not found', 'error_code': 400, 'ok': False}`

What am I doing wrong? I got `myuserid` by sending `/getid` to `@myidbot` and I got my token from `@BotFather`

Comment: You need to have written to the bot, before the bot can send you a message.

Comment: what is get id command? maybe its not user id and its bot id

Comment: He means the [@myidbot](http://telegram.me/myidbot) which does return the user id.

Comment: @Maak when I write to the bot, I just get an immediate answer about default commands.

Comment: @Maak How do you write to the bot?

Comment: @Maak how to write to a bot?

Comment: @elliotching i said in my original post.. `I got myuserid by sending /getid to @myidbot`

Answer (score 52, accepted):

As [@maak pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41174831/telegram-bot-chat-not-found#comment69551690_41174831), you need to first send a message to the bot before the bot can send messages to you.

Comment: How do we get their bot's name?

Comment: How to accomplish this? I have opened bot's page in Telegram and typed something. This didn't help

Comment: I am so confused, there are simply no way to get "chat_id" anyway

Answer (score 28):

I was using prefix @ before the value of chat_id as suggested everywhere. I removed it and it started working.
Note: if your chat id is 12345678 then you need to prefix it with -100 such that it is -10012345678.
Example Postman call:

```
/sendMessage?chat_id=-10012345678&text=Let's get together
```

Comment: This should be updated in Telegram docs. I wasted hours trying out various things before I found the solution.

Comment: Adding -100 is totally wrong. Why you want to do that? He wants to write to a private chat. Group ids start with -100. You can't just add that, because you'll try to send a message to random, unknown group or channel.

Comment: That did the trick for me. Probably because the group in question is of type "Supergroup".

Answer (score 10):

If your trying to send messages to a **group**, you must add a ‘-‘ in front of your chat ID.
For example:

```
TELEGRAM_REG_CHAT_ID="1949275XX"
```

should be

```
TELEGRAM_REG_CHAT_ID="-1949275XX"
```

Comment: This is not the case. You need to message the bot before it can message you

Comment: This is not asked. Especially group ids start with `-100`.

Comment: This worked for me too - is this documented anywhere?

Answer (score 3):

For me it worked only with `@` prefix before channel id

Answer (score 2):

Telegram bots can't send messages to user, if that user hasn't started conversation with bot yet, or bot is not present in chat (if it's a group chat). This issue is not related to the library, this is simply Telegram restriction, so that bots can't spam users without their permission.

you need to first send a message to the bot before the bot can send messages to you.

Answer (score 1):

There is a way to send notifications messages to telegram. It's a bit tricky but the tutorial is great!

http://bernaerts.dyndns.org/linux/75-debian/351-debian-send-telegram-notification

I just sended a message of my apache state to a privat channel.
Works also on public channel but it's not what i wantet. As you call a script (bash) you can prepare the parameters in any script language.

Hope that helps.

Comment: the link is broken

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use a bot message to the channel, you can refer step here

Steps:

1. Create a Telegram public channel
2. Create a Telegram BOT (for example `x_bot`) via BotFather
3. Set the `x_bot` as an administrator in your channel

the chat_id is `@x_bot`, it's a part of `https://t.me/x_bot` that does not add your channel name.

Answer (score 1):

I had some trouble with this after upgrading to a supergroup. The chat_id was updated and it was a bit harder to find this new id.

In the end I solved this with this by following this comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56078309/14213187

Comment: I faced the same issue. Which solution did you mean? using getUpdates?

Comment: **https://api.telegram.org/botToken/getupdates
Find the related message in output JSON and grab chatId. It will allow you to answer back with**

This part @bilogic

Answer (score 0):

If you use a username, it does not require any prefix. That means the following are incorrect:

```
https://t.me/vahid_esmaily_ie
t.me/vahid_esmaily_ie
```

And this is the correct case:

```
vahid_esmaily_ie
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you **use user id instead of username** if you're sending message to user.

From [the docs](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#sendmessage):

| Parameter | Type | Required | Description |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| chat_id | Integer or String | Yes | **Unique identifier for the target chat** or username of the target channel (in the format `@channelusername`) |
| ... | ... | ... | ... |

To get the chat id programmatically, see [Getting updates](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#getting-updates) for ways to get `Update` JSON object. For example, when a user sends a message, the [`Update`](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#update) object will have a [`Message`](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#message) object inside it which has a [`Chat`](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#chat) object which has the chat `id`. Turns out the chat id is the same as the user id.

Answer (score 0):

using the user_id in int() form worked for me